# Jquery Mobile Strange Behaviour with listviews

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement a code where I have a listview divided between 4 collapsible contents. When you open a collapsible, there is a bunch of options for the user to click. If he clicks in one of the options, the application must show how many times the option was clicked and the header of the collapsible must display the total of clicks the options inside the respective collapsible.

I'm having problem with the markup, not so much with the javascript logic. According to the docs, a span class='ui-li-count' inside a li tag is enough to display that kind of information. But it is presenting a strange behaviour. In some li the info is displayed, in others is not. There is also problems with formating and all.

```
I made a fiddle to better show : http://jsfiddle.net/j1ugkee4/
```

How can I make jquery mobile show correctly this kind of information?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of one UL containing the collapsibles. Have individual ULs in each collapsible body like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true">
    <h3 id="categoria-falta">Faltas Eliminatórias 
        <span id="counter-total" class="ui-li-count">0</span>
    </h3>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>Desobedecer à sinalização semafórica de parada obrigatória 
            <span class="ui-li-count">6</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span id="button-remove-falta" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">-</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/j1ugkee4/3/)**